# Why would rows match but not be changed with a mysql update statement?

Tags: mysql

I'm used to MSSQL, not Mysql, so sorry for this probably stupid question. I'm trying update my password for a backup database I'm getting setup by running the following query:

```
update users set password = md5('pass') where username = 'admin'
```

When I run this it says

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
>   Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

Why is a row matching but not changing?

Comment: Do you have the permissions to modify this table?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means that the value was not changed.  It was probably not changed because the column was already equal to the md5 hash of `pass`.

Comment: oh duh, didn't realize the first query worked (it was hidden in mysql bench)

Answer (score 0):

Another explanation for this behavior exists, though perhaps it's a strange edge case. I spent several minutes trying to change an integer flag on an ENUM column.

```
update users set status = 2 where id = 1999;
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected
Rows matched: 1 Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

I had forgotten the field "status" was an ENUM, Since it was, the value needed quoted:

```
update users set status = '2' where id = 1999;
```