# How to update target table in FROM clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-update

I prepared the following SQL statement in order to update the field `master_id` of the `staging` table with the `id` of the corresponding row of the `master` table. The `master` contains objects which are **unique by their location**. Therefore one id at maximum should be returned if at all.

```sql
UPDATE staging 
SET master_id = (
  SELECT m.id 
  FROM master m, staging s
  WHERE m.lat = s.lat 
  AND m.lon = s.lon
);
```

The query however fails with `You can't specify target table 'staging' for update in FROM clause`. How can I fix this?

Also I think the query can be optimized using a `JOIN`. If you can help with this it would be greatful!
Here is my try on joining both tables:

```sql
UPDATE staging s
INNER JOIN master m
ON s.lat = m.lat
AND s.lon = m.lon
SET s.master_id = m.id;

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.38 sec)
Rows matched: 14976  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Next try:

```sql
UPDATE staging s 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id, lat, lon
  FROM master
) AS m
ON s.lat = m.lat
AND s.lon = m.lon
SET s.master_id = m.id;

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.35 sec)
Rows matched: 14976  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Please mind, I am using MySQL if this affects the syntax of your solution.

---

To confirm that there are actually matching rows (each <-- this is intended) this query should proof the fact.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM master m, staging s
WHERE t.lat = s.lat
AND t.lon = s.lon;

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    14976 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

Comment: Did you meen to have **AND m.lon - s.lon**  or should it be **AND m.lon = s.lon**?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting every master_id in your table to this:

```
  SELECT m.id 
  FROM master m, staging s
  WHERE m.lat = s.lat 
  AND m.lon = s.lon
```

Contrary to what you think, this will return many rows. Try it as a standalone query! SQL doesn't magically understand that you want only the m.id that has lat and lon matching the row you're updating.

SQLFiddle is down at the moment, so I can't double-check, but you might want something like this:

```
UPDATE staging 
SET master_id = (
  SELECT m.id 
  FROM master m
  -- where m.lat,m.lon  are the lat,lon values **in the row you're updating**
  WHERE m.lat = staging.lat 
  AND m.lon = staging.lon
);
```

Note that this will set to NULL every master_id value in staging for which no matching (lat,lon) is found. That may or may not be an issue.

Comment: Can you please review your answer? I don't see the difference to my query. Still none of the rows is updated.

Comment: Maybe none of the rows have (lat,lon) that match your master table.

Comment: They all match since it is a copy of the table. See my updated post.

Comment: Maybe they already have the correct value in the master_id column. To get more useful help, give CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements with exact data for which this query doesn't work.

Comment: Also have you searched the internet for help understanding why you would see "Rows matched: <large number>  Changed: 0" For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148980/why-would-rows-match-but-not-be-changed-with-a-mysql-update-statement

Comment: You need to convert your last two comments into an answer because: Your are perfectly right. It sounds mad but I really did not notice that the ids were already set. Thanks so much.