# SQL UPDATE with LIKE => 0 rows affected

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table structure like this

```
iid                 int(11) Auto Increment   
itemId              varchar(50) 
itemTitle           varchar(100)    
itemSubTitle        varchar(200)    
itemDescription     text    
itemKeywords        text    
itemOrderId         int(11) 
itemContentType     varchar(10) 
itemIconURI         varchar(200)    
itemLargeIconURI    varchar(200)    
itemOpenData        text    
itemStatus          tinyint(4)  
itemFileName        varchar(255)     
syncCategories      varchar(255)     
itemShow            tinyint(4)   
itemCrc             varchar(40)  
itemLastUpdate      int(11)
```

One record of the table got "hn.applicant.draft" in itemKeywords field.
When i try this query

`SELECT * FROM item WHERE itemKeywords LIKE '%applicant%'`

the right record is returned. But if i try to update like this

`UPDATE item SET itemCrc='d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e' WHERE itemKeywords LIKE '%applicant%'`

it results in "Query executed OK, 0 rows affected."

What's the problem ?

Comment: Random thought - maybe `itemCrc` already has the value `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e' for this record?

Comment: @Galz if that was the case. Shouldn't the row be updated anyway ?

Comment: @Spin0us Is your table name is `item' ? may you r quering on other table

Comment: @t-clausen.dk NO. If there is nothing to update, MySQL will say 0 rows updated.

Comment: @Galz ok, I should stick to tsql. Thanks

Comment: No my table name is not item, but ombs_item, i just replaced for the post. And you're right t-clausen.dk, it was because of the value.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Depending on the client interface and settings, one may see *"Rows matched: 1 Changed: 0"*. Check this answer, too: [Why would rows match but not be changed with a mysql update statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148980/why-would-rows-match-but-not-be-changed-with-a-mysql-update-statement)

Comment: For C, you can change this with `CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` flag/parameter when connecting with [`mysql_real_connect()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-real-connect.html) For connections from PHP, there are probably similar settings/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [Galz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/610995/galz) says the value was already the good one. That's why 0 rows affected. I was trying to debug a php script, testing the resquet manualy, and not notice this. I feel so stupid :)

Comment: Don't feel (stupid.) Many other DBMS don't check the existing value and do the Update operation anyway. MySQL is an exception in this regard.