# Why my sql REGEXP_REPLACE is not changing all matches?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm using `mariadb` with this code:

```
UPDATE files SET file_source = REGEXP_REPLACE (file_source, 's:[1-9][1-9][1-9]|s:[1-9][1-9]|s:[1-9]', "s:12") WHERE type = 2;
```

I want to change all the columns where `s:` is followed by up to 3 numbers, and replace it with `s:12`

But when I run this it says:

```
Query OK, 10012 rows affected (0.118 sec)
Rows matched: 10375  Changed: 10012  Warnings: 0
```

I don't understand why? How I can see what didn't change and why? Is there a error in my code?

Also if I run this twice, it will say 0 changed, but from my understanding, this code should change everything again to `s:12` even if it's already `s:12`or am I wrong?

Comment: Unmodified rows do not count as "changed" rows, see [Why would rows match but not be changed with a mysql update statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11148980)

Comment: Give us a test case that fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine

```
Update Table1 SET file_source = 
REGEXP_REPLACE (file_source, 's:[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]', 's:12') Where TYPE = 2;
```

With s:1
s:31
and s:111

See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=506350e8fa09b7270fb5e8b46c2e2f6f

Comment: Good catch at 0-9 instead of 1-9. Thanks